# Exploring integration possibilities for a higher-order differential equation

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

**Problem,**

$$
U^{5}U^{(5)}+5U^{4}U^{\prime}U^{(4)}+5U^{4}U^{(2)}U^{(3)}+\frac{5}{2}U^{3}(U^{\prime})^{2}U^{(3)}+cU^{\prime}=0
$$

$U = U(x)$,$c$ is a constant, and I want to know if the left-hand side of the given differential equation corresponds to the derivative of a function. I am not aiming to solve the differential equation; instead, I intend to simplify it through integration for ease of further analysis. In fact, this process is one step of the '[tanh method](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0096300303007458)'.

**My attempts,**

It is easy to see that the antiderivatives of $U^{5}U^{(5)}+5U^{4}U^{\prime}U^{(4)} + cU^{\prime}$
is $U^{5}U^{(4)} + cU$. But $5U^{4}U^{(2)}U^{(3)}+\frac{5}{2}U^{3}(U^{\prime})^{2}U^{(3)}$ seems impossible to be the derivative of a function. So I tried again to check if the left-hand side is the second derivative of some function, but this idea was quickly ruled out. However, I want to know if there exists a function $F$, such that
$$
\frac{dF}{dx}=U^5U^{(5)}+5U^4U'U^{(4)}+5U^4U^{(2)}U^{(3)}+\frac52U^3(U')^2U^{(3)}+cU'
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint for analyzing the equation:

You should look into the following triangle, where $U^{(n)}(x+k) = U^{(n-1)}(x+k+1)-U^{(n-1)}(x+k)$:

$$U(x),U(x+1),U(x+2),U(x+3),U(x+4),U(x+5)$$
$$ U'(x),U'(x+1),U'(x+2),U'(x+3),U'(x+4)$$
$$  U^{(2)}(x),U^{(2)}(x+1),U^{(2)}(x+2),U^{(2)}(x+3)$$
$$ U^{(3)}(x),U^{(3)}(x+1),U^{(3)}(x+2)$$
$$ U^{(4)}(x),U^{(4)}(x+1)$$
$$ U^{(5)}(x)$$

Some of the values in this triangle are constrained by the equation.

Comment: Using this iteration, the formula seems to become more complex and can hardly use integration by parts I think?

Comment: Using the triangle, integration is just "moving from line with U'(x), to a line with U(x)"